# Golang - Problem during parsing boolean variable in Invidious API

Tags: go

I'm trying to check if the video is a live stream (URL is given below) via Invidious API. The variable "res.liveNow" displaying whether the video is a live broadcast must be true in this case, but is false. If I print "body" as a string, "liveNow" appears to be true.
What causes the problem here?

API URL: https://invidious.snopyta.org/api/v1/videos/nV1lL74IBTQ?fields=liveNow,title,author&pretty=1

Video URL: https://invidious.snopyta.org/watch?v=nV1lL74IBTQ

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

type Video struct {
    TrackID string `json:"videoId"`
    Title   string `json:"title"`
    liveNow bool   `json:"liveNow"`
    Author  string `json:"author"`
}

func main() {
    client := &http.Client{}
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://invidious.snopyta.org/api/v1/videos/nV1lL74IBTQ?fields=liveNow,title,author&pretty=1", nil)
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    resp, err := client.Do(req)

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    var res Video
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &res); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Can't unmarshal json")
    }
    fmt.Print(res.liveNow) // Should return true. Returns false
}
```

Comment: Upper case the field `LiveNow bool   \`json:"liveNow"\`` so it's an exported field.

Comment: @colm.anseo It's working. Thank you so much!